# How to do an Arrhenius plot AKA How to do a reciporcal secondary axis in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

An Arrhenius plot show the logarithm of a property that is thermally acitavted versus the reciprocal temperature aka 1/T. Now is 1/T something that most people are not used to. This is why most of the plot also contain the translation in temperature on a second axis. Usually on top of the graph. The output should look like this:

[image]

[Picture Source](http://blog.originlab.com/graphing/display-celsius-as-top-axis-in-arrhenius-plot)

The second axis is only for better readability and is corresponds to the primary axis with the relation:

```
primary=1/secondary 

secondary=1/primary
```

**What I am not able to do in excel 2010 is the reciprocal second x-axis.** Is there a way to do this?

A secondary problem is that I am not able to insert a secondary axis in a XYScatterplot

## Problem 1: How to format an axis reciprocal (1/x)?

## Problem 1b: How to properly add a second x axis in a XYscatterplot?

Note: If you know a solution to this using Macros (VBA) then my related question on StackOverflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259023/how-to-do-an-arrhenius-plot-using-excel-vba-aka-how-to-do-a-reciprocal-x-axis)

Comment: I don't think it would be possible neither with neither without VBA. You can get close by manually creating the secondary axis and placing it over your chart.

Comment: @MátéJuhász yeah.. I feared that the manual solution was going to be the final verdict. Ok better get started on the coding then.

Comment: You may also want to consider PowerBI and R.  With their integration with Excel, you may be able to accomplish your task without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://peltiertech.com/reciprocal-chart-axis-scale/) excplains how it is done. This would also work for other scaling axis like square root ect. Here a small outline of how you do it:

**Create your ticks as a series:**

- calculate all axis ticks you want the x's of a series
- all y's of the series need to be exactly the lowerlimit of your y axis (or the upper limit if you want your axis to be on top)

**Add Datalabeling**

- The markers of your series will now your ticks, after adding datalabeling, every tick can be labeled with the respective, in this case, temperature
- The line and marker are formatted to "none" like this only the label is visible

**Gridlines can be added using errorbars**

- add errorbars to the series
- format the errorbars to have no ending
- set the length of the errorbar to be the height of the plot

This game can be repeated for the y-axis if you want to.